# Importing Of Custom Solution Failed

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-365

I try to import my custom solution in a Dynamics 365 CRM but it causes an error.

The import of the solution ABC failed. The following components are missing in your system and are not included in the solution.

> Import the managed solutions that contain these components
> (ProjectService (3.10.0.31),msdyn_Geofencing (1.0.0.238),FieldService
> (8.8.0.88),ConnectedFieldService
> (1.7.7.107),msdynce_CoreServiceScheduling
> (9.0.19122.1010),MicrosoftDynamicsScheduling (3.12.0.448)) and then
> try importing this solution again.

Anyone know the solution?

Comment: The message speaks for itself, it seems that there are some dependencies to other solution components in your solution

Comment: ok, I have to import these managed solutions first in order to import this one?

Comment: Yes, it would be best way

Comment: what componenets do you have in your ABC solution? looks like you are trying to have all (kind of default) components in your ABC solution and probably the issue.
Maybe trying adding only minimum required components in your ABC solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can install the First party managed solutions like Field service, Project service, RSO, etc from https://admin.powerplatform.microsoft.com/

Choose the environment -> Resources -> Dynamics 365 apps and install them. After that you will be able to import your solution.

[image]

[image]